Is there any out of box functionality to get the airflow logs in JSON?
I want the airflow logs to be in JSON. I can see a config in the elasticsearch section which is to format logs in JSON but I am not using ES so setting that doesn't work for me. I have seen some solutions using customer logging mechanism to achieve the same, but there is no solid implementation of it or the guide to do so. I want the logs to be displayed in JSON in the UI and also in the files.
Any help in appreciated.
I tried implementing a custom formatter, but for some reason airflow is not picking that up and displaying the logs in the UI as it is. I want the logs displayed in the UI in JSON too.
